# In powershell with psreadline -EditMode VI how to ensure the cursor starts at the end of the line when going through history

Tags: powershell, psreadline

I'm using the powershell VI mode via

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode vi
```

It is awsome to be able to edit the line using VI commands however there is one thing that is annoying. When using the up and down arrows to navigate history the cursor always starts at the start of the line instead of at the end. ie: if I had the following command in my history

```
svn help x-shelve --list
```

then I would want the cursor *(represented by the pipe | )* to be like

```
svn help x-shelve --list|
```

rather than

```
|svn help x-shelve --list
```

is there a way to set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler` cmdlet:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow `
   -ScriptBlock {
     param($key, $arg)

     $line=$null
     $cursor=$null
     [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::HistorySearchBackward()
     [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref]$line, [ref]$cursor)
     [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::SetCursorPosition($line.Length)
}


Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key DownArrow `
   -ScriptBlock {
     param($key, $arg)

     $line=$null
     $cursor=$null
     [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::HistorySearchForward()
     [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref]$line, [ref]$cursor)
     [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::SetCursorPosition($line.Length)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the option was added in a later version or something, but the below answer is much simpler and more "correct"

Answer (score 5):

Use the same `Set-PSReadLineOption` cmdlet that you used to get into VI mode:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -HistorySearchCursorMovesToEnd:$true
```

You can see which options can be set with `Get-PSReadLineOption`:

```
Get-PSReadLineOption
```

and the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption) includes a few useful examples